# trouble using the angular delete request wtih express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I want to execute a delete request to my express server using angular.

```
remove: function (id) {
            return $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: '/users/remove/'+ id
            })
        }
```

in my express server I have this

```
router.delete("/remove/:id", cors(), function(req, res){

console.log("server");

})
```

The problem is that im getting a 404 error. I'm using the methodOverride module to allow my server to handle this request.

Comment: your url and route need to match. If you are following "normal" uri conventions, your URL should be `url: '/users/'+ id` and your route should be `router.delete("/users/:id", ...`.

Comment: I assume that `router` is mounted on `/users`? And I think `methodOverride` is useless in your situation (although it won't be causing the problem).

Comment: @RyanWheale yeah good point, the `remove` in the URL is superfluous.

Comment: just a bit ;) - I also made the assumption that if he's having trouble with a fairly basic endpoint, that he's not mounting a sub-app or other "advanced" express techniques like that.

Comment: Yes the router is mounted on "/users"

Comment: @user3862830 do you also have a route handler for `OPTIONS`? See [this](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight). It may be that the CORS preflight request is causing the 404.

Comment: the funny things is that I have a form with a put request and it works. action='/users/edit?_method=PUT', method='post', but that one is submitting a form now im trying to ajax a request so I have no idea how to transfer that code in javascript/angular. BTW I remove the cors() function and it's still a problem

Comment: This an actually joke. I ran my application in my server and it work. I was using localhost that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

localhost was the issue as soon as I ran it on the server it work.